# ASP.NET Core MVC: EF Core Migration Failing "Bulid Failed" when scaffolding identity

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to add identity scaffolding to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I am following the instructions from this page: [Scaffold Identity into an MVC project without existing authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization).

following the instructions to generate database code, I entered the following in the Package Manager:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore

PM> Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema

PM> Update-Database
```

However, the command `Add-Migration` fails. The only information provided is "Build failed."

Any ideas of what I need to do to make this work?

Using Visual Studio 2022, the project is an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

TIA

Comment: Check the message thoroughly. It gives the reason why the build was failed. For vs2022, it validate errors on the cshtml as well. However, this error won't show on the error menu.

Comment: `Add-Migration` attempts to build your solution first, but the build failed. Look at your Errors tab / build output to work out why. Build all of the projects in the solution, perhaps there has some build error. Try to solve them, and then execute the `Add-Migration` command again.

Answer (score 0):

Please install this package
PM> install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools